# App that allows to paste text snippets in any applicaton?

Tags: macos, automation, ios

I'm looking for an OS X application that will allow me to add text snippets, like common text responses to emails or signature postings or whatever standard text phrases I wish to save and resuse.

Something that perhaps runs in the background on the toolbar that allows me to select phrases and insert them when needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at CodeBox http://www.shpakovski.com/codebox/

or Dash http://kapeli.com/dash

or Clipmenu http://www.clipmenu.com

Answer (score 3):

The perfect tool for this job is [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html) - it allows you to insert snippets from a menu or using a shortcut such as ";;snippet". It is incredibly powerful and is high on my recommended list.

It's $35 but there is a free trial.

Answer (score 2):

[Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) with the PowerPack also lets you define snippets which are easily pasted anywhere. TextExpander as Tony Williams mentioned is a bit more convenient, but Alfred is cheaper and can do a lot more than just expanding snippets.

Answer (score 2):

there is a built in function in iOS and keyboard settings for Mac that offers shortcuts enter a shortcut and the phrase it expands into when you type the shortcut and a space afterwards.

it doesn't allow for line-breaks however

Comment: line breaks through alt + enter

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, like the freeware XMenu from Devon Technologies:

http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html

You define snippets by making a text clipping and placing them in a particular folder. The clippings menu resides in your menu bar.

It's also got a nice launcher a'la NowMenu. And as it is an App it doesn't modify the system and cause incompatibility issues like some other clippings apps do.

Answer (score 0):

I use PhraseExpress (http://www.phraseexpress.com) to paste in different boilerplate phrases. It even lets you create macros, select different options within your phrase, manipulate dates/times, and do simple calculations. It's on the pricier side though, $50. You can try it out for free, however.